# CIImage, CIDetector - how to find other objects in images other than faces

Tags: ios7, ciimage

Is there anyway to find other objects in images without having to integrate other 3rd party libraries like openCV and write all the algorithms myself..

i.e. if i wanted to locate anything an in image that looks like a door? or locate anything that looks like a number 1...9?

Is there support to pass in a 2D shape image, and a photo, and have IOS try to find that shape in the photo file?

Comment: With the iPhoneX being able to detect faces for FaceID, surely there will be lots of advancements in the image detection iOS libraries...Anyone know?